# Convex set in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: general-topology, analysis, convex-analysis

I want to show that the set $A=\{(x, y)\in\mathbb{R}^2: x^2\leq y\} $ is convex.

Comment: It is a convex set in $\mathbb R^2$. You fix the title. Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Let $x, y \in A$,   so $ x=(a, b) $  and $y=(x, y)$, hence $a^2  \leq b$ and $c^2  \leq d$.   we are going to show that $[x, y]   \subset A$.  Let $w  \in  [x, y] $ so,$ w=(1-t) x +ty$,  with $t \in [0,1$]. So,  $w=(1-t) (a, b)  + t(c, d)  = ((1-t)a +tc, (1-t)b +td)$.  I want to show that $[(1-t)a+tc]^2\leq (1-t)b td.  So   [(1-t)a+tc]^2 = (1-t)^2a^2 +t^2c^2 +2(1-t)atc.$ The problem is i dont know how to bounded $2(1-t)atc$

Comment: Using $x, y$ for different things is a bad idea. You should directly expand your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definition: a convex function is a function $f:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ such that $A_f = \{(x,y):y\geq f(x)\}$ is convex.

Proposition: If for any $x_1, x_2\in \Bbb{R}$ and $t\in [0,1]$ we have $f(tx_1+(1-t)x_2)\leq tf(x_1)+(1-t)f(x_2)$, then $f$ is convex.

Proof: Suppose the hypothesis holds. Pick $(u_1,u_2), (v_1,v_2)\in A_f$, so $u_2\geq f(u_1)$ and $v_2\geq f(v_1)$ *. Pick $t\in [0,1]$. We wish to show that $t\mathbf{u}+ (1-t)\mathbf{v}\in A$, i.e. $tu_2+(1-t)v_2\geq f(tu_1+(1-t)v_1)$. By hypothesis, we have
$$f(tu_1+(1-t)v_1) \leq tf(u_1)+(1-t)f(v_1) \leq tu_2 + (1-t)v_2$$
Where the last inequality is by *. This completes the proof.

Now we show that the proposition holds for $f(x) = x^2$. Let $x,y\in \Bbb{R}$, $t\in [0,1]$. Then
$$tf(x)+(1-t)f(y) - f(tx+(1-t)y) = $$
$$tx^2 + (1-t)y^2 - t^2x^2 - (1-t)^2y^2-2t(1-t)xy = $$
$$t(1-t)x^2+t(1-t)y^2-2t(1-t)xy = $$
$$t(1-t)(x-y)^2 \geq 0$$

Verifying that $f$ is convex. The proposition here is very useful for proving functions are convex; it's actually an "if and only if", but I omitted the other half as it wasn't necessary here.