# Prove that $a^4y^6+b^4x^6=(a^2y^4+b^2x^4)^2$, given $\begin{cases}a^2y^4+b^2x^4=a^2b^2\\a^2+b^2=x^2+y^2=1\end{cases}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

If $a^2y^4+b^2x^4=a^2b^2$ and $a^2+b^2=x^2+y^2=1$ then prove that $a^4y^6+b^4x^6=(a^2y^4+b^2x^4)^2$.

It is a question related to quadratic equations. I already tried using different methods like completing the square, but I couldn't find the correct way to prove it.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read the title.

Comment: Your problem would look simpler if you write your last equation under the form $a^4y^6+b^4x^6=a^4b^4$...

Comment: Please, try to make the titles of your questions more informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.*
From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: The claim fails for $(a,b,x,y)=(1,0,0,1)$.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe $\,(a,b,x,y)=(1,0,0,1)\,$ does not satisfy the condition $\,a^2y^4+b^2x^4=a^2b^2\,$.

Answer (score 2):

Eliminate the conditions $a^2+b^2=x^2+y^2=1$ by the parameterization

$$ a= \cos(\alpha)  \ \   ; \ \   b = \sin(\alpha)\\
x=\cos(\theta) \ \ ; \ \ y= \sin(\theta)$$
Where we take $\alpha,\theta \in (-\pi,\pi]$

Substitute in the condition $a^2 y^4 + b^2 x^4 = a^2 b^2$ to get
$$ \cos^2 (\alpha)\sin^4(\theta) + \sin^2(\alpha)\cos^4(\theta) = \cos^2(\alpha)\sin^2(\alpha) \label{asd} \tag{1}$$

Our goal further is to solve $\alpha$ in terms of $\theta$ using above equation.

One can verify that $\alpha= \pm \theta , \pi \pm \theta$ solve the equation. A simple way to actually solve is to use complex analysis by taking
$$ \cos(\alpha) = \frac{1}{2}\left(z_1 + \frac{1}{z_1} \right)\\
\sin(\alpha) = \frac{1}{2 i}\left(z_1 - \frac{1}{z_1} \right)\\
\cos(\theta) = \frac{1}{2}\left(z_2 + \frac{1}{z_2} \right)\\
\sin(\theta) = \frac{1}{2i}\left(z_2 - \frac{1}{z_2} \right)$$

and substituting in the equation $(1)$ to write an algebraic equation in $z_{1,2}$ which can be easily solved for $z_1$ in terms of $z_2$ as
$$z_1 = \pm z_2 \ \ ;\ \ z_1= \pm \frac{1}{z_2}$$

Now, we want to show, $a^4 y^6 + b^4 x^6 = (a^2y^4+b^2 x^4)^2 = a^4 b^4 \tag{2}$

Using the solution presented above,

$y^6 = b^6$ and $x^6 = a^6$

LHS of equation $(2)$ becomes
$$a^4 b^4 (a^2+b^2) = a^4b^4$$

Answer (score 1):

Taking the same notations as @lavneet giving rise to the identity

$$\cos^2 \alpha\sin^4 \theta + \sin^2\alpha\cos^4\theta = \cos^2 \alpha\sin^2 \alpha \tag{1},$$

let me give a second part of a proof that does not use complex numbers.

A preliminary remark: as $a,b,x,y$ can be replaced by their absolute values without loss of generality, we can assume that $a,b,x,y \ge 0,$ giving

$$\alpha, \theta \in [0, \pi/2] \tag{2}.$$

The second part of the proof: (1) can be transformed into:

$$\cos^2 \alpha (1-\cos^2 \theta)^2+(1-\cos^2 \alpha)\cos^4 \theta=\cos^2 \alpha (1 - \cos^2 \alpha)$$

giving, after expansion and simplification:

$$(\cos^2 \alpha-\cos^2 \theta)^2=0 \ \ \implies \ \ \cos \alpha=\pm \cos  \theta \ \ \implies \ \ \alpha=\theta$$

(due to the restriction (2))

As a consequence

$$\begin{cases}a&=&\cos \alpha&=&\cos \theta&=&x\\
 b&=&\sin \alpha&=&\sin \theta &=& y \end{cases}$$

Now the identity to be established is evident.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\,a^2=c, x^2=z\,$ then $\,b^2=1-c, y^2=1-z\,$ and the problem reduces to:

$$
\underbrace{c}_{a^2}\underbrace{(1-z)^2}_{y^4} + \underbrace{(1-c)}_{b^2}\underbrace{z^2}_{x^4} = \underbrace{c(1-c)}_{a^2b^2} \quad\implies\quad \underbrace{c^2}_{a^4}\underbrace{(1-z)^3}_{y^6}+\underbrace{(1-c)^2}_{b^4}\underbrace{z^3}_{x^6}=\underbrace{c^2(1-c)^2}_{a^4b^4}
$$

Moving all terms to one side in the LHS equality and expanding the square:

$$
\require{cancel}
\begin{align}
0 &= c(1-z)^2+(1-c)z^2 - c(1 - c)
\\ &= (\cancel{c}+1-\cancel{c})z^2 - 2 c z + c(\cancel{1} + c - \cancel{1})
\\ &= (z-c)^2
\end{align}
$$

Therefore $\,z=c\,$ and the RHS equality follows trivially.

Comment: [+1] You have reduced the issue to its "skeleton" ! I am puzzled by this very simple identity $a(1-b)^2+(1-a)b^2=(a-b)^2$ for which I have no intuition. It looks in correspondence with convexity issues like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1890773/305862)...

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks. Don't know there is much to intuit behind that, but $\,(z-c)^2$ $=c(1-z)^2$ $+(1-c)z^2$ $-c(1-c)\,$ is an equality of two quadratics which obviously match at $3$ points $z=0,1,c$ so it might be possible to recast it as some sort of interpolation.